# DateTime go to first occurrence of hour/minute/second

Tags: c#, datetime

Given this datetime of January 1 2015 at 23:00 hours:

```
var someDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0);
```

And given the int `6`, which is the desired hour, how do I return the first following datetime where the hour is `6`? In this case, `someDate` and `6` would return a new DateTime of January 2 2015 at 06:00 hours.

Comment: You could do a loop that keeps adding an hour until the hour is 6.  That or check if the hour is less than 6 and add the difference, or when it's more then add 6 + (24 - current hour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply add the hours to the original *date* and add another day if the result is before the original time:

```
var someDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0);
var result = someDate.Date.AddHours(6); // note the "Date" part
if (result < someDate) result = result.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: `result < someDate` will always be false because you just added hours to `someDate`, so `result` has to be larger.

Comment: @juharr please read carefully: I added 6 hours to someDate. _Date_ !

Comment: OK I see what your doing.  Though It's not clear if the OP would want to lose the current minutes and seconds.

Comment: @juharr "The first following datetime where the hour is 6" is of course 6:00:00, as 6:00:01 would not be the _first_.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Fastest Gun in the West wins the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
public DateTime FollowingHour(DateTime start, int hour)
{
    DateTime atHour = start.Date.AddHours(6);

    if(atHour < start)
    {
        atHour += TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    }

    return atHour;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add one day to the date and six hours to the result:

```
var someDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0);
var result = someDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(6);
```

Note the use of `Date` property - it will give you the start od the day and from there it's easy to navigate forward.

Comment: That doesn't work for `new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)` where the answer should be `January 1 2015 at 06:00`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(someDate.Hour != 6){
    someDate = someDate.AddHours(1);
}
```

Comment: This also works, but if you're adding from hour 07:00, it's not nearly as efficient as the accepted answer. Or am I wrong?

Comment: at maximum it will be 23 iterations, not too many I think but yes, the accepted answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant 24h clock, you can try this:

```
    public DateTime GetDate(DateTime someDate,int hour)
    {
       return someDate.Hour>=hour? someDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(6):someDate.Date.AddHours(6);
    }
```